# Redirect languages for search engines by cookies

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, localization

I Wan't optimize my web-site to search engines with multi languages...
i have that structure with languages:

English - example.com/en/
Russian - example.com/ru/
Georgian - example.com/ge/

on first join to my website he automated set you language by your country.

(for Google and other bot's default language are english) and all robots searched on my site only English texts.

Anyone know how can I optimize website in search engines with languages?

E.G: [Google search example result](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3abestinvest.ge)

Comment: Could you rephrase your question so we can understand better and provide some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your language versions should provide links to the same content in the other languages, then google has a chance of finding out that the other versions exist. I personally also would consider it good form to provide a way for the use to chose languages by hand. You can't always trust the language preferences coming in from the browser.

Another solution could be to offer a site map that links to each and every article in every language; that way, Google can also at least find out that more stuff exists.